# IntelliJ - Android Project - Gradle Refresh Failed

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 on Windows 7 (64-bit).

I have created a project (with MainActivity). During creation, gradle was "refreshing" and then it failed.

> Gradle 'MyApp' refresh failed. Error:Connection timed out: connect. If
>   you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings
>   either in IDE or Gradle.

I am not using proxy. And still, I tried to add the following code in gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

After refreshing, the error was:

> Gradle 'MyApp' refresh failed. Error:Connection refused: connect

In the IDE's settings (Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle) I tried to change the default setting (I found this on the internet) from "Use default gradle wrapper" to "Use local gradle distribution", and at "Gradle home" I put the home directory on "gradle 2.10" after I downloaded it. I tried even with "gradle 2.14". After that I tried the "Offline work" setting (in the same settings area) -> and this gave me the following:

> Failed to sync Gradle project 'MyApp' Error:No cached version of
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0 available for offline mode. Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync
>   project

All these, and it still doesn't work.

I mention that I have java installed (jdk1.8.0_31) and SDK Manager.

I even tried to create a project in Android Studio, but there it is stucked on  Gradle Building (there it is worst, I think). Now I want to reach "My First Android App".

What am I doing wrong in IntelliJ with gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Try to  Restart Android Studio:

> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart and select Invalidate and Restart.

[image]

Comment: In Android Studio, the building get stuck with:
Gradle: Resolve dependencies ':app:_debugCompile'

Comment: remove all proxy settings if you have any, it looksl ike that you cannot download the required files